Serve wordpress and S3 website using Cloudfront
I have my main site at WPEngine hosted and a React based webpage hosted on S3.
Domain is setup on Route 53, I have created a cloudfront with 2 origins.
Origin 1 -> domain.wpenginepowered.com
Origin 2 -> s3-bucket-url

Behaviours:
* -> Origin 1
/path/* -> Origin2

Route 53 A of root domain points to this cloudfront distribution. When I visit domain.com, it works as expected. When I do domain.com/path, I get 404 error. Can someone please help with this issue.

What if you try domain.com/path/ (with the slash at the end?) or domain.com/path/file.txt (pointing to a real file)?
